# SAP BO 4.2 Report Export to Excel, PDF, CSV Excessive run-time

Tags: excel, business-objects

Has anyone run into an issue with exporting a report to **Excel, PDF, or CSV** on the SAP/BO server and had to wait up to 40 minutes for the report to finish exporting on the server?

- The report renders in **2** minutes or so, but the moment a user exports to Excel, PDF, or CSV on the server it takes up to 40 minutes.
- Report size was approximately **70MB**.
- After contacting SAP, their recommendation was to optimize the report and reduce the number of rows returned by the report.

Considering the report renders fairly quickly we believe there could be another issue occurring.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

That's not surprising; 70MB is pretty huge for an exported file.  Note that when you're viewing the report in WebI, you're only seeing a page at a time -- so it's not rendering the entire report.  It's also processing the report on the server, so only that one page at a time has to be transferred to your browser.

There are also a number of moving parts when you download the file:

- WebI report engine generates all data for the report
- Web app server (Tomcat, by default) renders the result into the desired format
- The file is transferred via HTTP
- Your browser receives the file and saves it

You *could* try scheduling the report instead, and deliver it to a file share.  That will eliminate the web app and browser steps.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond to my question.  This was very helpful.  I have a few follow-up questions.

Comment: After the initial 2 minute render time we can quickly navigate to the next page and so on in the report.  We discovered that the report downloads via HTTP to the user's machine in about 10 seconds.  It takes about another 10 seconds for Excel to open the report on the user's machine.  Based on my interpretation of your response - it seems that the report is large for B.O., and the Web app server could be in need of additional resources to speed up the Excel, PDF, CSV render.  Is that correct?  Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes.  If you have access to the server, you could open task manager while the report is processing to see what's active in terms of CPU and memory.  I expect you'll see high usage of both from the WebIProcessingServer first, then Tomcat.